# Lazy loading? Is it better to avoid it?

Tags: php, design-patterns, lazy-loading

I just read about the "lazy loading" design pattern.

Is it ok to overuse lazy loading to load all classes and forget about `include(..)` entirely? 
What are the cons of this approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A couple points on autoloading:

1. You will see a nice performance
   improvement by using autoloading
   versus always including all of your
   files all the time
   (especially as the number of files
   grows larger and larger).
2. When implementing autoloading, it is
   better to use
   [`spl_autoload_register()`](https://www.php.net/spl_autoload_register) than
   `__autoload()`.

Although a lot of times when people talk about lazy loading in PHP, they are talking about something like the following:

```
class Foo {
    protected $bar = null;
    
    public function getBar() {
        if ($this->bar == null) {
            $this->bar = ExpensiveOperation();
        }
        return $this->bar;
    }
}
```

Then you only load a property when it actually needs to be used, and not every time you instantiate the object, which can potentially have some good benefits.

Answer (score 3):

One benefit of a lazy loader is that it only loads the class files that are actually needed by the script during the course of its execution, potentially saving memory; when otherwise you might include all class files, whether they are needed or not. Depending on your scripts, this can make quite a difference.

Comment: Surely this is **the** benefit of a lazy loader?

Comment: @Will - No need for long lists of includes would be the other major benefit, and having to add to the list whenever you add a new class, is a secondary benefit; but the memory/performance improvement is certainly the primary benefit. Also prevents the overhead of include_once, while not having to worry about duplicated includes

Answer (score 2):

It is fine to use explicit includes, or to have `__autoload()` find your classes for you.  Either way.

I wouldn't recommend mixing the two strategies, though.  The `include` lines would be unnecessary.